# php array mysql pull

Tags: php, mysql

If I have an array like:

```
$b=array(1,6,8,9);
```

and I also have a mysql table with:

ID (this is an integer, like the array elements), code, time

and I want to get the time for each ID number in the array $b, how can I do this?

I am currently using a mysql_query for each array element in a for loop, this seems bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (is_array($b)) {
  $ids = implode(',', $b);
} else {
  $ids = $b;
}

if ($ids !== '')
{
  $result = mysql_query(
    "SELECT ID, code, time
    FROM YourTable t
    WHERE
      t.ID IN ($ids)");
}
```

This will give you a query result of multiple rows, where each row contains the matched ID and the corresponding code and time.

Comment: would this work only for 1 digit integers?  like not for array(1,4,5,72,39,3)?

Comment: Nope. $b is expected to be an array. It *can* be an array of one item. You can also check if it is an array.

Comment: I added this check in the example.